# Is "chill" out of place to say to someone after a not so particularly good exam?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, slang

I am not a native speaker of English.
Now, this was the conversation:

> A: How was today's exam?
>
> B: It was just okay.
>
> A: Well, you've got 2 more, right? You'll do well in those. Now when you say "okay" I believe yesterday's wasn't bad either. Anyways,
>   *chill*. Good luck with your next exam.

Now, is the usage of *chill* appropriate in context?

Also, how acceptable is the reply by A in terms of selection of words (again keeping in mind the context)?

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se]. It was pretty much created for questions like this one.

Comment: user59014, the word is *anyway* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/anyway?q=anyway , not "anyways".

Comment: @Tristanr Except when it is *anyways* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/anyways . not "anyway."

Comment: choster, I noticed that your link says "informal for **anyway**".

Comment: The letter *s* in "anyways" is superfluous. It is an unnecessary, added extra. It is surplus to requirements. It is just there for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're goal was to communicate "relax" there's nothing more you can do about it, then yes, it was 100% right.

Comment: In other words, was that like telling him to "get over it already" Couldn't that also be interpretted as "relax and drop your worries about that exam"

Comment: That is correct - although the proper phrasing would be "relax and don't worry about that exam"

Comment: Sorry, i do realize this is a language forum but in your opinion do you think that was an insensitive slang for the moment.

Comment: "Chill out about it" would be the expected way of "stop worrying." I personally would take "Anyways, chill. Good luck with your next exam." in the context of your quote as some form of "Take it easy" (Goodbye/see you later). In other words: if you *meant* to say "stop worrying about that exam," then "chill out about it" would have been the right choice. As far as politeness, that depends on your relationship with the individual and whether saying such things is overstepping your friendship.

Comment: "Chill" might, under the circumstances be overstating it, but not extremely far off the mark.  Personally, I would use the word if the other person seemed to be experiencing **undue** stress over an issue.  But if experiencing only understandable stress, I would rather say "No worries."  Or something equally mild.

Answer (score 0):

The word "chill" in this type of context generally has a negative connotation in my experience. It tends to be said to people who are perceived as acting overly emotional or aggressive.

Ex. "Hey man, chill out" said to someone who just had a drink spilled on them and is now trying to pick a fight.

That being said, the manner in which a word is spoken often changes the meaning. A drawn out "hey, chiiiill" could be construed as legitimately soothing, or at least intended to be; it could also be patronizing.